# How to get a list of all distinct prefixes in S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, python-s3fs

If I have a directory structure as below and the prefix is /folder1,

```
/folder1/folder11/folder12/folder13/*.files
               /folder21/folder22/folder23/*.files
               /folder31/folder32/*.files
```

I want to loop through these directories dynamically in order to read files in each of the leaf folder separately, i.e. I'd need a list

```
[
 /folder1/folder11/folder12/folder13/, 
 /folder1/folder21/folder22/folder23/,
 /folder1/folder31/folder32/
]
```

Is there a better way to get it other than loop through each prefix recursively, get next level prefix, concatenate, get next level, etc., until you get to the last (leaf) folder?

Comment: Formatting made it a bit misleading, the /folder1 is common, the rest are subfolders: /folder1/folder11/folder12/folder13/*.files;
/folder1/folder21/folder22/folder23/*.files;
/folder1 /folder31/folder32/*.files

Comment: The looping is the way you do it. Alternatively, can get S3 inventory to identify the prefixes of interst before you start iteration.

Comment: The S3 storage is "flat" meaning there is no actual directory structure. So as you said, your best choice is to do a BFS for each prefix.

Answer (score 2):

When listing objects from Amazon S3, if you specify `Delimiter='/'`, then it will return a list of `CommonPrefixes`. This is effectively a list of subdirectories for the given `Prefix`.

However, I suggest that you do not think about directories. Instead, just loop through *all* objects and look at the `Key` to know the path of the object.

If you just want a list of paths that contain files, use this:

```py
import boto3

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
folders = set()

# Find paths of all non-empty objects (to exclude zero-length 'folder' objects)
for object in s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET).objects.all():
    if object.size > 0 and '/' in object.key:
        folders.add(object.key[:object.key.rfind('/')])

print (folders)
```

Comment: Thank you, this will definitely work.  In an unrelated utility I actually do get all object keys and store them in a set to whittle down to unique values.  I was just thinking if there are lots of files in each "leaf folder", it could become unreasonably slow.  Thank you for a code sample, will use it!

Answer (score 2):

you can use this in a loop to get just the prefixes

```
def get_list_of_prefixes_from_prefix(bucket, prefix):
    """gets list of prefixes for given bucket and prefix"""
    list_of_prefixes = []
    paginator = boto3.resource('s3').meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects')
    for result in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
        # print(result)
        if 'CommonPrefixes' in result:
            prefixes = [f['Prefix'] for f in result['CommonPrefixes']]
            list_of_prefixes.extend(prefixes)
    return list_of_prefixes

list_of_prefixes = get_list_of_prefixes_from_prefix('my-bucket', 'my-prefix/')
```

Comment: Yes, maybe it wasn't clear when I mentioned to use it in a loop. Capture the prefixes in list_of_prefixes, then iterate on that list, etc. I didn't have a use case for that, so 1 level was ok with me.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a [S3 inventory report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) and and process the data using Athena. The Athena table structure for the report is also mentioned in the same AWS article. This is the serverless approach of doing the same.

Comment: Thank you, will research

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3

list_of_prefixes = []

def get_list_of_prefixes(bucket, prefix):
    global list_of_prefixes
    paginator = boto3.resource('s3').meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects')
    for result in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
        if 'CommonPrefixes' in result:
            for f in result['CommonPrefixes']:
                get_list_of_prefixes(bucket, f['Prefix'])
        else:
            list_of_prefixes.append(prefix)
    return list_of_prefixes

list_of_prefixes = get_list_of_prefixes('my-bucket', 'my-prefix/')

for i in list_of_prefixes:
    print(i)
```

Comment: This is a recursive way to gather prefixes without de-duping keys for individual objects.  Critique is welcome, I am new to Python and boto3.

Comment: After testing, this recursive solution is actually slower than pulling all objects and chopping off file names.