# Move files with certain extension from multiple S3 objects to another S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have the following S3 bucket structure:

```
s3://<bucket_name>/
|---object_1/
|   |---images/
|   |   |---<image_11.jpg>
|   |   |---<image_12.jpg>
|   |---annotation/
|   |   |---<image_11.xml>
|   |   |---<image_12.xml>
|---object_2/
|   |---images/
|   |   |---<image_21.jpg>
|   |   |---<image_22.jpg>
|   |---annotation/
|   |   |---<image_21.xml>
|   |   |---<image_22.xml>
```

I want to move all the images and annotation files together into two separate S3 objects respectively such that the destination object structure looks like:

```
s3://<bucket_name>/
|---all-images/
|   |---<image_11.jpg>
|   |---<image_12.jpg>
|   |---<image_21.jpg>
|   |---<image_22.jpg>
|---all-annotation/
|   |---<image_11.xml>
|   |---<image_12.xml>
|   |---<image_21.xml>
|   |---<image_22.xml>
```

## Question

I have tried the solution from this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021661/copy-multiple-files-from-s3-bucket) but it does not change the S3 object structure. All the files are copied with the folder names (here, `object_1/images/image_11.jpg`). I want all the images together without the directory structure under one object (here, `all-images/<all_the_jpg_files>`). How can I achieve that using AWS CLI or Sage Maker notebook instance?

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

Create a list of prefixes using [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777183/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-distinct-prefixes-in-s3-bucket) as the reference.

### Step 2

Iterate over the list of prefixes (here, `object_1`,`obkect_2`...) and `cp` or `sync` the source bucket with the destination bucket. The following command is the one I used on Sage Maker notebook instance.

```py
!/bin/bash  
for label in list_of_prefixes:
    !aws s3 cp --recursive 's3://<bucket_name>/f"{label}"/images/' 's3://<bucket_name>/all-images/'
```