# Using Amazon S3 Java Api, can you use --query within ListObject?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently, I'm transferring files from one bucket to another that are little over a year old. In order to do that, I'm using to ListObjects method, and then filter accordingly. However, it's pulling all files, including those that over 2 years old. Is there a way filter out those older files without prefix?

Thank you,

Comment: To filter Amazon S3 objects, you use the ListObjectsRequest object's prefix method. This is the reason for the ListObjectsRequest object's prefix  method. See https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/ListObjectsRequest.html#prefix--

Comment: @smac2020 is there another option other than using prefix? If not, is there a way to get list of prefixes in a bucket?

Comment: S3 does not do this kind of server side filtering. You have to filter on the client side as you're already doing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777183/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-distinct-prefixes-in-s3-bucket. It will point you in the right direction.

Comment: One thing that you can do instead of listing and moving is us a [lifecycle policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.